# Generate Int mapping for String in List

Tags: scala

Using this code I'm attempting to output an Int value that corresponds to string value in List :

```
   val l = List("a" , "b" , "b" , "a");
    var counter = 0;
    var isAdded = new scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String]();
    val map = scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.empty[String,Int]        

    def getId(m : String) : Int = {
        if(map.isDefinedAt(m)){             
            map.get(m).get
        }
        else {
            map += m -> counter
            counter = counter + 1
            counter
        }
    }

    (l.map(m => getId(m))).foreach(println)

1
2
1
0
```

is outputted when I'm expecting `1,2,2,1` , each Int is sequential and unique in how it maps to the element in List. If List contained ("a" , "b" , "b" , "a" , "r") then `1,2,2,1,3` should be generated.
I understand this is an imperative solution attempt but I'm attempting to try an imperative solution before converting to functional.

How to generate a unique List of sequential Int values that map to the values in the List ?

Answer (score 2):

```
scala> val chars = List("a" , "b" , "b" , "a" , "r")
chars: List[String] = List(a, b, b, a, r)
```

Make a `Map[String, Int]` out of the distinct characters that will be used to lookup the numeric value for each character in `chars`.

```
scala> val map = chars.distinct.zipWithIndex.toMap
map: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 0, b -> 1, r -> 2)
```

Now, go through the list and get the numeric value for each character.

```
scala> chars.flatMap(c => map.get(c) + 1)
res1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 2, 1, 3)
```

I think an imperative approach would be more difficult to reason about.

Comment: thanks but I receive error : , type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Int(1)
[error]  required: String
[error]         val output = l.flatMap(c => map.get(c) + 1)
 , 
I instead used : chars.map(c => map.get(c).get + 1)

Answer (score 1):

Your counter is incremented at the wrong place. This fixes it:

```
def getId(m : String) : Int = {
        if(map.isDefinedAt(m)){             
            map.get(m).get
        }
        else {
            counter = counter + 1  // should be incremented before adding to map
            map += m -> counter
            counter
        }
    }
```